# My .env.local won't load when using an NPM workspace

Tags: npm, dotenv, npm-workspaces

My root package.json has:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/common",
    "packages/webapp",
    "packages/indexer"
  ]
}
```

In `packages/indexer/.env.local`, I have:

```
PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT=us-west4-gcp
...
```

In my `packages/indexer/package.json`, I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/queue.ts"
  },
```

And queue.ts has:

```
// packages/indexer/src/queue.ts
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { GCPPubSubService } from './services/gcp.pubsub.service';

dotenv.config();

console.log(process.env)
```

But it doesn't have my environment variable. What am I missing?